# Превратности функции Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Скорее хочу поделиться, хотя неплохо было бы и узнать ответ. На днях столкнулся с интересной особенностью Canvas-a.

При построении оси координат при задании маленьких чисел записывается только пару чисел которые нравятся самому canvas-y.

Чтобы не быть голословным вот примеры:

```
sch.textAlign = "left";
sch.textBaseline = "middle";
x = useX(0);
for (mark = 0.1; mark <=zmax+zmax/10; mark += 0.1) {
    y = useY(mark);
    if (mark % 0.2 == 0) {
        sch.fillText(String(mark), x + 10, y);
        sch.fillRect(x + 4, y - 0.5, 3, 1);
    }
    else sch.fillRect(x + 2, y - 0.5, 3, 1);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при внесении небольших изменений (увеличения всех чисел на 10) всё работает.

```
sch.textAlign = "left";
sch.textBaseline = "middle";
x = useX(0);
for (mark = 1; mark <=zmax*10+zmax; mark += 1) {
    y = useY(mark/10);
    if (mark % 2 == 0) {
         sch.fillText(String(mark/10), x + 10, y);
         sch.fillRect(x + 4, y - 0.5, 3, 1);
    }
    else sch.fillRect(x + 2, y - 0.5, 3, 1);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще сейчас всё работает отлично, но всё так хотелось бы узнать с чем это было связано. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже мне удалось найти ответ на этот вопрос. Но если я всё таки ошибся, кто это будет читать поправьте )

Всё дело в том, что в стандарте IEEE 754 на число выделяется ровно 8 байт(=64 бита), не больше и не меньше.

Число 0.1 (одна десятая) записывается просто в десятичном формате. Но в двоичной системе счисления это бесконечная дробь, так как единица на десять в двоичной системе так просто не делится. Также бесконечной дробью является 0.2 (=2/10).

Ну и вот доказательства:

```
alert( 0.1.toFixed(20) ); // 0.10000000000000000555
alert( 0.1 + 0.2 > 0.3 ); // true
alert( 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 ); // false
```

Ну и прочие подобные радости например как эта:

```
alert( 9999999999999999 ); // выведет 10000000000000000
```

Из 64 бит, отведённых на число, сами цифры числа занимают до 52 бит, остальные 11 бит хранят позицию десятичной точки и один бит – знак. Так что если 52 бит не хватает на цифры, то при записи пропадут младшие разряды.

В общем зря я грешил на canvas, это проблема двоичной системы счисления, надеюсь это будет кому-нибудь полезно, хотя бы для саморазвития )

Comment: К сожалению, у Вас не получилось пересказать своими словами IEEE 754 спецификацию восьмибайтного типа double.